# Custom Icon assigned to menu items not working for multi-site networks

Tags: plugins, customization, admin-menu, icon

I have assign different custom font icon to each menu item using the_title action hook and is working for single site but not working for multi-site networks. Is there any solution for this issue? How to make custom icon that is displayed in front of menu items to display on multi site as well and make it compatible with WPML Plugin?

Comment: When you say "not working" do you mean the icon just doesn't appear, or something else? Can you show us the code you have? I can't think why this wouldn't work for multi-site networks. Do you already have problems with WPML or are you just asking about that too?

Comment: Yes, I am currently facing the issue of not appearing menu icon on other site (multi-site). There is no any problem with WPML. The icon that I want to append in front of menu item is dynamic. The icon is set from backend option and is displayed on frontend.